# Maven packages in the a different version than dependency:tree shows

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

I have a dependency structure similar to this:

```
A:compile
    com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.7.1.RELEASE:compile
        com.google.guava:guava:jar:r06:compile
    com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0:compile
```

That is, my project depends on A, which depends on Guava 13.0 and BoneCP (which depends on Guava r06).

When I run `mvn clean dependency:tree | grep guava` I see:

```
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0:compile
```

Which, as far as I understand Maven's dependency resolution, is what is supposed to happen.

However, when I run `mvn clean package` and unpack the resulting jar, it seems Guava r06 has been included. In A, I am relying on functionality that is in Guava 13.0 but not r06, so I get a runtime failure (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Table`).

I am using the shade plugin (1.4) to create the jar with all dependencies included. Here is the result of `mvn --version` (on our build server, where I am having this problem):

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: /opt/apache/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-5-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

On a different machine (my local workstation), the packaged jar contains Guava 13.0 as I expected. The version info on that machine is:

```
/usr/java/default
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rNON-CANONICAL_2011-06-28_14-50_mockbuild; 2011-06-28 10:50:25-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_27
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.43.8-1.fc15.x86_64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Did the change from Maven 2.2.1 to 3.0.4 change the dependency resolution strategy? What is going on here?

Comment: The differences in dependency resolution are documented here: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution

Comment: Thank you, I think that explains it. The different results between the jar and dependency:tree were especially confusing me. If you'd like to put this in an answer I'll accept it.